# Is this really equal to sin x?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Link to image: https://i.redd.it/uj2a83j468yy.png 
Is this really true? I can't prove or disprove it.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! This is not only true, it is the rigourous definition of $\sin x$. To prove it in an elementary context, use the power series expansion of $\mathrm e^u$, and set $u=ix$: $\sin x$ is the imaginary part, by *Euler's formula*.

Comment: Ultimately it depends on _how_ you're defining the $sin$ function.  If you're not already familiar with Taylor series it's not going to be easy, so if you want to learn how to write a formal proof of this I'd recommend you read up on some real analysis notes.  In my real analysis lectures, we defined the $sin$ function like this, so it's true by definition.

Comment: The more traditional understanding is that $\sin x$ is defined geometrically, and from that you prove (i) what its derivatives are and then (ii) the formula you gave, which is the Taylor series for $\sin x$.  It's in calculus books, e.g., Stewart's *Calculus* secs. 3.5, 12.10 and Appendix D (1999 ed.).  An exemplary free calculus book:  http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/38769?msg=welcome_stranger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with
$\sin'(x) = \cos(x),
\cos'(x) = -\sin(x),
\sin(0) = 0,
\cos(0) = 1,
\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$,
you can proceed like this
(not original with me):

$$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\le\int_0^x dt
=x
$$
$$\cos(x)-\cos(0)
=\int_0^x -\sin(t) dt
=-\int_0^x \sin(t) dt
\ge-\int_0^x t dt
=-\frac{x^2}{2}\\
\text{ so }
\cos(x)
\ge 1-\frac{x^2}{2}
$$
$$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\ge\int_0^x (1-\frac{t^2}{2})dt
=x-\frac{x^3}{6}
$$
$$\cos(x)-\cos(0)
=\int_0^x -\sin(t) dt
=-\int_0^x \sin(t) dt
\ge-\int_0^x (t-\frac{t^3}{6}) dt
=-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\\
\text{ so }
\cos(x)
\le 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}
$$

By induction you can
derive the power series
for sin and cos
and show that they are
enveloping
(the sum is between any two
consecutive sums).