# Proving $x-\frac{x^3}{6} < \sin(x) < x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} ~~ \forall x \in \Bbb R^+$ using Taylor's expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to prove

> $$x-\frac{x^3}{6} < \sin(x) < x - \frac{x^3}{6} +  \frac{x^5}{120} ~~ \forall x \in \Bbb R^{+}$$

I wrote $\sin(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!+\dots$ and then the expression for $\sin(x)-(x-\frac{x^3}{6})$ i.e. $x^5/5!-x^7/7!+x^9/9!+\dots$.

I don't see why $x^5/5!-x^7/7!+x^9/9!+\dots$ should be positive for all positive real $x$. Any idea?

Comment: That certainly has to be invalid for $x \le 0$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think my book is wrong then. Anyhow, how do you prove it for $x>0$ ?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I've modified the question after your comment

Comment: you can try to prove a more general result: suppose that $(a_n)\downarrow 0$ and $s:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k a_k<\infty$, then $$|s_n-s|\le a_{n+1},\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$$ where $s_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k a_k$.

Comment: @Masacroso That argument will only work for small $x$.

Comment: If $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ then another argument would be to use the Taylor series theorem with remainder term: $\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} \cos c$ for some $c$ between 0 and $x$.  And similarly, $\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{7!} \cos c_2$ for some $c_2$ between 0 and $x$.

Comment: Just a note that for $x<0$ inequalities are reversed. This is easy to see since all the functions are odd.

Comment: @DanielSchepler For large values of $x$, the argument is trivial, since the lower bound goes to $-\infty$ while the upper bound goes to $+\infty$.  So indeed, Masacroso's approach is quite valid.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes, it's certainly possible another argument such as yours could supplement it for large $x$.  All I was saying was that as it stands, it requires $\frac{x^7}{7!} < \frac{x^5}{5!}$, or $x < \sqrt{6 \cdot 7}$.

Comment: Here's a similar way: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316231/prove-that-x-frac16x3-sinxx-frac16x3-frac1120x5-for-so/2316465#2316465

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390899/proving-that-x-fracx33-sin-x-x-for-all-x0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$f(x) = \sin x - x + \frac{1}{6}x^3$$
and
$$g(x) = x - \frac{1}{6}x^3 + \frac{1}{120}x^5 - \sin x$$
We want to show $f(x) >0$ and $g(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$.

Notice that $f$ and its first four derivatives vanish at $x=0$.  If $f$ has a positive zero, say $f(a_0) = 0$, then by Rolle's Theorem $f'$ has a zero $a_1$ with $0 < a_1 < a_0$.  Repeating this argument, we have $0 < a_4 < a_3 < a_2 < a_1 < a_0$ with $f^{(n)}(a_n) = 0$.  Since $f^{(4)}(x) = \sin x$, we must have $\pi \le a_4$, so $\pi < a_0$.  This shows $f(x)$ does not change sign for $0<x<\pi$.  Since $-x + (1/6) x^3 > 3/2$ and is increasing for $x > 3$ while $\sin x \ge -1$, we see that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.

To see that $g(x) > 0$ for $x>0$, observe that $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$, $g''(x) = f(x)$, and $f(x) > 0$ for $x>0$, as we just showed.

Answer (score 4):

For any $x>0$ we have $\sin(x)<x$, hence by applying $\int_{0}^{t}(\ldots)\,dx$ to both sides we get $1-\cos t < \frac{t^2}{2}$. By applying $\int_{0}^{x}(\ldots)\,dt$ to both sides we get $x-\sin x<\frac{x^3}{6}$, which can be rearranged as $\sin(x)>x-\frac{x^3}{6}$. By performing the same trick again we also get $\sin(x)<x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}$ and the wanted inequality is proved for any $x>0$.

An equivalent approach is noticing that
$$ \iint_{0\leq a \leq b \leq x}(a-\sin a)\,da\,db,\qquad \iiint_{0\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq x}(a-\sin a)\,da\,db\,dc $$

are clearly positive.
We are dealing with odd functions, hence the reversed inequality holds over $\mathbb{R}^-$.

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice trick. Any idea how to directly prove $x^5/5!-x^7/7!+x^9/9!-....>0$ (for positive $x$) though?

Comment: @Blue: $$ \frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\ldots = \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{a}(u-\sin u)\,du\,da $$ is the integral of a positive function. Just the same argument in disguise.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Prove that

$$1-\frac {x^2}{2}\le \cos (x)\le 1-\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^4}{24} $$

and integrate.

to prove this, it is easier to show that

$$-x\le -\sin (x)\le -x+\frac {x^3}{6} $$

or the easiest

$$0\le 1-\cos (x)\le \frac {x^2}{2} $$

then integrate twice between $0$ and $x $.

> Taylor expansion give only local information.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The Maclaurin expansion of $\sin$ is alternating, and for "small enough" values of $x$, the absolute value of the terms are monotonically decreasing. What can you say in general about bounding an alternating series who's terms monotonically decrease?

For "large enough" values of $x$, it is good enough to notice the lower and upper bounds are not in $[-1,1]$ and to then observe that the lower bound is monotonically decreasing while the upper bound is monotonically increasing.

Comment: How can you say that the terms are monotonically decreasing for $|x|>1$ ?

Comment: @Blue Is it not obvious? For $x\in(0,1]$,$$x^{2n+1}\le x^{2n+3}\\\frac1{(2n+1)!}<\frac1{(2n+3)!}\\\implies\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}<\frac{x^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)!}$$

Comment: From what you wrote it seems that that it is monotonically "increasing" rather than decreasing. $x^5/5!<x^7/7!$ (for $|x|>1$)

Comment: Indeed, with good enough Stirling approximations, you can show that by the third order, the terms are decreasing for $x\in(0,3]$.

Comment: My question was for all positive reals. Not $(0,3]$

Comment: @Blue But note I have covered the case when $x$ is "large", the upper and lower bounds are outside of $[-1,1]$, so there is no problem verifying there.

Comment: Secondly, $\frac{1}{5!}>\frac{1}{7!}$. What you wrote is wrong (i.e. $\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}>\frac{1}{(2n+3)!}$).

Comment: @Blue Oh, whoops, my comment above is absolutely backwards. Please switch all of those inequalities lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63888/discussion-between-blue-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: For $x\in(0,1]$ and $n>1$,$$x^{2n+1}\ge x^{2n+3}\\\frac1{(2n+1)!}>\frac1{(2n+3)!}\\\implies\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}>\frac{x^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

All of them fit in this infinite sequence of inequalities:

$$\frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} - \cdots \ge 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}  \\
\frac{x^3}{3!} - \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^7}{7!} -\cdots > 0 \ \forall x>0 \\
\frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} - \cdots > 0  \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R^*}\\
\cdots \cdots \\
$$

It's enough to show the first sum is $\ge 0$ and $>0$ for $0<|x|< \epsilon$, and notice that the derivative of any of those sums is the previous sum. The first inequality follows from the identity of power series 
$$\frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} - \cdots= 2 \left( \sum_{k \ge 0}\,(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2^{2k+1}(2k+1)!}\right)^2$$ which one can check directly.